# Google Chrome: Key-in of hyphen, L/R arrow keys not possible on HTML input or textarea fields

Tags: html, google-chrome, meteor, keyboard-events

Working on a Meteor app (v. 1.5.1) with Framework Blaze.js and have noticed that all input and textarea fields do not recognize key-in of hypens, or left and right arrow keys inside Chrome (v.67.00.3396.87).

This is a production-level bug that precludes entering an email address with a hyphen and also doesn't allow users to navigate through an entry with arrow keys. Email addresses with hyphens that are copied and pasted are accepted and recognized as valid so it is not an issue of pattern matching or validation. Further, the problem can only be noticed after navigating away from the form page and back.  For example, if app is launched directly to form or search field, hyphen and arrow keys work as expected.  But once one navigates away and comes back, hyphen, left and right arrow present as dead keys (keycodes 189, 37, 39, respectively).

Users need to be able to enter hyphens as part of email addresses, and not have to use copy and paste. Also, users would like to be able to use arrow keys to navigate through input entries before submission. To be clear, this is not a validation problem, since hyphens are accepted as part of email fields.  The issue is that hyphens cannot be keyed in.  Also, bug does not exist when app is launched in Firefox.

Keyup, keydown event recognizes these keys (hyphen, L/R arrow), but no action or character recorded inside field.  I cannot find much about other users having this issue. My best guess is that there is interference with some Meteor package in use within the app.  Does anyone have any suggestions or clues?  Anyway to override the behavior?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide some more credentials in order to improve the chance of getting a helpful answer: Please provide your OS, browser version, meteor version (meteor release), which front end framework (and version) do you use? Production or development?

Comment: Linux OS, Chrome Version 67.0.3396.87 (Official Build) (64-bit), Meteor release version 1.5.1, Production issue